# Solving nonlinear recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve a nonlinear recursive relation that reads
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{f(n+1)} = \frac{1}{f(n)+A} + B, \quad \text{for} \quad n=1,2,\ldots
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are two positive constants. Is it possible to solve these exactly and/or approximately (eg, for large $n$) and obtain a form for $f(n)$, assuming $f(1)$ is known?

Any input would be appreciated as I know very little about recursive equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac 1 {f_{n+1}}=\frac 1 {f_n+a}+b\implies f_{n+1}=\frac{f_n+a } {b\,f_n+(1+ab) }=\frac{\frac 1bf_n+\frac ab } {f_n+\frac{1+ab}b }$$

Let $m=\frac 1b$, $x=\frac ab$, $y=\frac{1+ab}b$ to make
$$f_{n+1}=\frac {m\,f_n+x}{f_n+y }$$ and have a look to my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693) where all steps are detailed.

Comment: This is great! I didn't fully read the references cited in the said Wiki page - could you possibly spell out what $K$ is in $A_n$ and $B_n$ in your other answer?

Comment: @SaMaSo. It is the constant to be fixed by the value of $f_0$

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in the following way:

$$u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n+A}{Bu_n+C} \ \text{with} \ C:=AB+1$$

This kind of recurrence is called a homographic sequence, and there are standard ways to express its general term ; see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2158473/305862) explaining the connection with geometric or arithmetic sequences. In your case, the "fixed point equation" is given by the quadratic:

$$Bx^2+ABx-A=0$$

has always 2 real roots because $\Delta=(AB)^2+4AB >0$.

A matrix treatment is also possible: see this old answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2445574/305862).

Comment: Thank you. Minor issue, but is it not $B x^2 +AB x-A=0$ ?

Comment: You are right. I correct it.